# getDay() not working in Firefox with certain date format

Tags: javascript, weekday

This code syntax works with Chrome & Safari, but not with Firefox.

> I think it could be to do with the **date format(dd-mmm-yyyy)**.

How do I get all 3 browsers to work with this date format?

```
var weekday = new Date('14-Mar-2018').getDay();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arnoldtm/q6epxy7b/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp), `The behavior of  "DD-MM-YYYY" is also undefined.
Some browsers will try to guess the format. Some will return NaN.`

Comment: Thanks @pfg - Changed format to 'yy-mm-dd' and it works on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Changed format to 'yy-mm-dd', as 'dd-mm-yy' was undefined on Firefox